# How to I calculate the occurrence of items of one column after grouping after another?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count

I am trying to calculate how my session_ids the users have. This is what the dataset looks like:

```
User     Session id 
1        1
         2
         3
         4
2        5
         6
```

How to I get the amount of sessions attributed to each user?

I want the output to look like this:

```
User  session_count
1     4

2     2
```

Comment: `df.value_counts('User')`

Answer (score 0):

```
session_count = df.groupby(["User"])["Session id"].count()
```

will save the results to a new dataframe called session_count and show the following output:

```
User
1    4
2    2
```

Or

```
session_count = df.groupby(["User"])["Session id"].count().reset_index()
```

to get the output in separate columns like this:

```
    User    Session id
0   1       4
1   2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Users': [1,1,1,1,2,2],
   'Session_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6]
})

df = df.groupby(['Users'])['Session_id'].count().reset_index().rename(columns = {'Session_id':'Session_count'})
```

[output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzrYL.png)